# How to replace all links in HTML with one div element with Javascript/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to replace all links in HTML with one div element?

For example : I have link code as :

```
<div class="link"><a href="stackoverflow.com">Stackoverflow</a></div>
<div class="link1"><a href="stackoverflow.com/link1">Stackoverflow</a></div>
```

I now want replace to become as :

```
<div class="link">replaced link</div>
<div class="link1">replaced link</div>
```

I need your helps. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3):

this will do -

```
$('a').replaceWith('replaced link');
```

Demo `--->` http://jsfiddle.net/Txmrx/5/

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to replace with the link href which make more sense than your example in question:

```
$('a').replaceWith(function () {
    return '<div>'+$(this).attr('href')+'</div>';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var as = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
while(as[0]){
  as[0].parentNode.replaceChild(document.createTextNode('replaced link'), as[0]);
}
```

Comment: Didn't notice the jQuery tag.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if I not clear read you question, if you want do change div content

```
$(function () {
var _newLink = [{
    href: 'newlink.com',
    title: 'New Link Title 1'
}, {
    href: 'newlink.com/link2',
    title: 'New Link Title 2'
}];

$('div[class*=link]').each(function (i) {
    var _divContent = '<a href="' + _newLink[i].href + '">' + _newLink[i].title + '</a>';

    $(this).html(_divContent);
});
```

});

[here my demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FdN3F/)